# What does `with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts.` mean here?

Tags: adverbs, semicolons

The target sentence
https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/

> Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.2 or any later version published by the Free Software Foundation; with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts.

To divided it into two parts.
part1

> Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.2 or any later version published by the Free Software Foundation

part2

> with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts

There is a semicolom between part1 and part2.

From part1, people can copy ,distribute ,modify the document under GNU license,i knew it.

How about part2?

1.Part2 is a  independent sentence which omit some important thing--verb.
If it is ,please write the whole sentence.

2.part2 is just a part of part1
Part2 is like a adverbs to modify part1?If it is so,to use semicolon between them is incorrect.

Which one is correct?
And what is the meaning  of "*with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts.*"

Comment: It is not clear whether the *with*-phrase modifies the noun **document**, or the noun **version**, or the infinitive phrase **to copy, distribute, and/or modify**. The semicolon is incorrect. I believe it to be the infinitive phrase which is being modified, or at least a piece of it. Those three sections off the document are what you cannot modify. But that belief is based on my understanding of those three terms, not on the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the meaning "with no Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts."

The used license, GFDL, has optional features, "invariant sections" and "cover texts". Some licenses, for example, this GIMP license, do not use those features. In this case, the license should just mention it has no invariant sections and cover texts. Richard Stallman [proposed to use this phrase](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-howto-opt.html) to opt-out.
In case you're curious, "invariant section" is a part of the license that the others are not allowed to modify or exclude, and the "cover texts" must be printed on the covers in case the document is printed.

> How about part2?

It seems to be an independent sentence:
Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document; with no (meaning, "it has no") Invariant Sections, no Front-Cover Texts, and no Back-Cover Texts.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with this question/answer is that the word no here is rather too vague. with "cover texts", which seems to apply to photos/diagrams etc,  no does not mean that you are not allowed to overprint the image with your own text, it means the opposite, there is no requirement to overprint the image with text supplied by the creator - eg there is no requirement to overprint the image with the contributor's name.

See https://www.gnu.org/licenses/fdl-howto-opt.en.html#SEC2 for more details